# What's the background of this exercise in Godement's Algebra (Exercise 14.1,2)

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8l8F.jpg
There are many matrices here so I post a picture.These are two exercises in Godement's Algebra, which are trivial.However, what's the background of these identities? I know the symbol [] is Lie bracket, but is there something deeper in these matrices whose shapes are special?
Thank you!

Comment: Well the Lie algebra in the beginning is $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C)$, but viewed as six-dimensional *real* Lie algebra. What exercise 2 does is to give an explicit representation of the same Lie algebra as real matrices on a four-dimensional real space, presumably in a standard form of what is often called $\mathfrak{so}_{1,3}$. Would that suffice as answer to your question?

Comment: Thank you very much!The answer I need is "standard form".

Comment: I don't quite understand?

Comment: Ok nothing. I had the feeling that these matrices represent something canonical object(like standard basis in $\mathcal{R}^n$),but it's vague. And you told me that it's actually a standard form of the Lie group.Thx!